# Recommended max file upload size for PHP based website?

Tags: php, upload, user-experience

From an UX prospective without concerns of technical boundaries, I expect the correct answer is "the maximum size which legitimate users of a given application need to upload".

Given my expected user base, I expect 10M will be common and as such allowed. But should I increase this limit to 20M, 50M, 100M, or more?

I pondered whether I should post this question here, or under https://ux.stackexchange.com/ as both have bearing.  From a UX perspective, a user doesn't wish to break files apart, but also doesn't wish to wait an excessive long time to receive feedback that an upload was completed successfully, nor require recipients which download their files to do similarly.

I am now currently looking for answers from a coding perspective.

From a technical perspective, what is the recommended maximum upload file which should be imposed, and if larger files are required, the user must be educated to take other means?  Please explain reasons why.

PS.  If you feel this question should be marked down, do so as you wish, but please comment as why as I feel this question has not been well addressed in the industry and would like to edit my question to make it more applicable if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your limit is really up to you and it depends on the size files you're generally getting to be uploaded. Personally I've never needed to allow users to upload over 20MB files at a time through PHP, anything larger I've just given people FTP access and they can upload through an FTP client with larger files.

Using other technologies such as jquery, you can have file uploads which show progress such as [this](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which ends up making the upload process far more user friendly.

In a hypothetical situation if I owned a media design website that massive files had to be uploaded to e.g. 20MB PSDs, I would probably allow larger files, however I would limit who could upload these files (not just some random person that used the register forms).

This is more of a personal opinion than a technical answer, so feel free to vote it down.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I would have to vote down my own question first before down voting yours!  For my application, users are vetted.  In your hypothetical web design owner situation, would you limit it to 20M, 40M, or larger, and if so, why?  Why couldn't PHP be used to implement the same upload file sizes as a FTP client?